# ssl-pinning right approach for android and IOS application

Tags: android, ios, ssl-certificate, cloudflare, sslpinning

We are using Cloudflare as our edge. We have the requirement for SSL pining. could any suggest the best way to manage SSL pining [ Dynamic cert approach ] .

Comment: https://mailapurvpandey.medium.com/ssl-pinning-in-android-90dddfa3e051 This article illustrates it in detail.

Answer (score 1):

This is addressed in the [SSL FAQs](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/204144518-SSL-FAQ#h_3k3bHm83HfwEKwYEeKg6v8) on the Cloudflare Documentation

[image: Certificate Pinning documentation from Cloudflare]

The [Certificate Transparency monitoring service](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/edge-certificates/certificate-transparency-monitoring) could be used to fulfil  the requirement. Alternatively, you may be able to implement by using [Custom Uploaded certificates](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/edge-certificates/custom-certificates) - these certificates are not managed by Cloudflare but created and uploaded by the account owner, and must be renewed manually.